# Automatic onTap action of GestureDector widget within horizontal ListView

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a horizontal listview of containers that change colour on tap. I want to make "pressed" and "unpressed" such that only one container can be pressed at a time, if another container is pressed the former pressed container repaints to the unpressed color. I was going to go about this using a stateful widget with a callback function that uses the setState method to change the colour and update a map that contains the colour states of each container.

To start off I just wanted to print to console of the container I was pressing, but it seems like it pressed multiple containers at once. How can I fix this? If there's a better way to go about changing colours of containers please do share.

Container widget code:

```
class Box extends StatefulWidget {
  int color;
  int index;
  Function callback;

  Box(this.color, this.index, this.callback);

  @override
  _BoxState createState() => _BoxState(color, index, callback);
}

class _BoxState extends State<Box> {
  int color;
  int index;
  Function callback;

  _BoxState(this.color, this.index, this.callback);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: callback(index),
        child: Container(
            width: 150.0,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(color),
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: Center(child: Text("${index + 1}"))));
  }
}
```

Page where I implement horizontal listview:

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  int _selected;


  var pressStates = {
    //Color states of each container
    //unpressed = 0xFFD0D0DE
    //pressed = 0xFF8A2BE2

    1: 0xFFD0D0DE,
    2: 0xFFD0D0DE,
    3: 0xFFD0D0DE,
    4: 0xFFD0D0DE,
    5: 0xFFD0D0DE,
    6: 0xFFD0D0DE,
    7: 0xFFD0D0DE,
    8: 0xFFD0D0DE,
    9: 0xFFD0D0DE,
    10: 0xFFD0D0DE,
    11: 0xFFD0D0DE,
    12: 0xFFD0D0DE,
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    callback(int index) {
      _selected = index + 1;
      print("tapped ${index + 1}, state: ${_selected}");
    }

    final _test = ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: pressStates.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Box(pressStates[index + 1], index, callback);
        });

    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
      body: new Container(height: 300.0, width: _width, child: _test),
    );
  }
}
```

Console output:

```
I/flutter (11600): tapped 1, state: 1
I/flutter (11600): tapped 2, state: 2
I/flutter (11600): tapped 3, state: 3
I/flutter (11600): tapped 4, state: 4
I/flutter (11600): tapped 5, state: 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will print ok if you just replace the `onTap` property with

```
onTap: () { callback(index); },
```

But you should refactor your code to make the Test class a StatefulWidget because it holds the state for the selected circle. And make the Box Stateless.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: TestPage(),
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TestPageState createState() {
    return new TestPageState();
  }
}

class TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  int _selected;

  var selectedColor = 0xFFD000DE;
  var unselectedColor = 0xFFD0D0DE;

  callback(int index) {
    _selected = index;
    setState(() {});
    print("tapped ${index + 1}, state: ${_selected}");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    final _test = ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: 12,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Box(
            _selected == index ? selectedColor : unselectedColor,
            index,
            callback,
          );
        });

    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
      body: Container(height: 300.0, width: _width, child: _test),
    );
  }
}

class Box extends StatelessWidget {
  final int color;
  final int index;
  final Function callback;

  Box(this.color, this.index, this.callback);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          callback(index);
        },
        child: Container(
            width: 150.0,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(color),
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: Center(child: Text("${index + 1}"))));
  }
}
```

Comment: This works!  Quick question why is setState method used with no function? I thought  _selected = index would be inside it

Comment: Also what is the purpose of typedef VoidCallback MyCallback(int index);

Comment: `setState()' just adds some asserts and checks if the function is a future. Apart from that, calling the function outside has the same effect as calling it inside.

Comment: I have removed the MyCallback(). It was a leftover of some test.